# Programmatically determining whether a verb is intransitive

Tags: java, nlp

I'm trying to use the [SimpleNLG](https://github.com/simplenlg/simplenlg) system to turn verb phrases into passive voice, past-tense verb phrases. For example:

> "bear in Virginia" --> "was born in Virginia"

However, intransitive verbs cannot take on passive voice:

> "die in Virginia" -/-> "was died in Virginia"

Thus, I want to be able to detect if the verb in the original verb phrase is intransitive so that I don't apply the passive voice. Is there an API that provides information about the transitivity of a verb?

Comment: did you try wordnet?

Comment: As a possible solution, you may create a special pos tag for the verb, i.e. VBI in your case, and add that to the training.